# Remembering last open state

Tags: jquery

On the site http://www.ryancoughlin.com/hp/?c=posters, I am using this code for the left hand side:

```
$(".menu-header").click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle('slow');
        return false;
}).next().hide();
```

If you open one of them and hit another section, it closes, is there any way to keep that state open?

Comment: I updated my answer to be more complete, its not very pointful copying the answer into the question, its more pointful for me to make my answer better and for you to accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

Your sections maintain their open-state fine, but they get closed when you open *new* page.

Your question does not disambiguate between these 2 concerns however.

What you might like do to to make it work on those pages is inject a variable to work out what page you're on.

```
   jQuery(function($){ 
     var matches;
     if( matches = (new String(document.location)).match(/\?c=\w+/) ) {  
        $("a[href=" + matches[0] + "]").parents("ul").toggle(); 
     }
   });
```

Aught to work as a short-term solution though.

So the full code would be ( annotated )

```
/* Document Ready, $ = jQuery inside this scope regardless  */

jQuery(function($){  

  /* Bind the click event on all the menus, then hide them all. */

  $(".menu-header").click(function() {
            $(this).next().toggle('slow');
            return false;
  }).next().hide();
  /*
   * Check to see if we're already on a sub-menu-item
   * By looking in the current pages url for the string '?c=somewordhere'
   */
  var matches;
  if( matches = (new String(document.location)).match(/\?c=\w+/) ) {  
    /*
     * If we are, search the page for a link to that submenu item
     * ( by looking for the '?c=somewordhere' part in the hrefs ) 
     * and find its parent menu `ul` and show it.
     */
    $("a[href=" + matches[0] + "]").parents("ul").toggle(); 
  }

}); # End Document Ready Scoping.
```

For clarities sake,

```
jQuery(function($){ 

});
```

Is a very handy shorthand notation which is very powerful.  It's equivalent to doing

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

});
```

Which in turn is almost equivalent to doing

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
     var $ = jQuery; 
});
```

Which guarantees in a failsafe way that "$" will be jQuery inside this function regardless of everything else on the page.

Comment: hey kent, thank you. so how would I manipulate this in to my code?

ryan

Comment: Oh...I see..I wouldn't need to add that to my code block I have now?

Comment: Hey Kent, could you also explain that code a bit? Just so I know.. thank you

Comment: It is checking if the current page has a ?c=<SOMETHING> in the URL, if it does it finds the link in the page that is pointing to this URL, finds the parent ul, and toggles it (which will show it since the page just loaded and it is initially hidden)

Comment: Thank you! Does my updated code above look corect. I am not sure how to implement that in to my code.

Ryan

Comment: Kent, thanks a ton for this, thanks for explaining that code, hopefully others can learn this as well. Works great. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [reallysimplehistory](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/).  It allows you to save state between page calls transparently (no need to mess with cookies, URL's, etc.)

You could also use Ajax for your site, but if you want the back button to work, you'd use something like RSH anyway.  =]